# Envío de validación de mail al registrar usuario en Laravel: Verify no funciona

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Tengo un registro de usuario por Google Socialite que anda perfecto. El usuario recibe el mail de validación hace clic en el enlace y accede al sitio.

Por otro lado cree un login personalizado, el mail llega bien pero al hacer clic sobre el mismo **no actualiza el campo** **EMAIL_VERIFIED_AT**.

> Mi controlador RegisterController.php

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return $user = User::create([
        'tipo_usuario' => $tipoUsuario,
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'apellido' => $data['apellido'],
        'telefono' => $data['celular'],
        'telegram' => $data['telegram'],
        'documento' => $data['documento'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
    event(new Registered($user));
}
```

En [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification) indican que se debe agregar el evento:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

event(new Registered($user));
```

Y en mi oyente EventServiceProvider.php tengo:

```
Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
```

En mi sistema de rutas:

```
Auth::routes([
    'verify' => true,
]);
```

Pese a que **agregué el evento** no funciona ¿Qué estaré haciendo mal o que me puede faltar para solucionarlo?

Comment: Nada que pongas después de un `return` va a ejecutarse.... El return hace que se salga del flujo actual ( de la función create en este caso) y siga por donde iba antes de entrar a la función. Por cierto, esto es así en todos los lenguajes de programación y en todos los paradigmas... y de hecho el significado literal de return ya te da una pista de esto, siendo ***VOLVER***

Comment: Francamente no me había dado cuenta. event(new Registered($user)); en este evento necesito utilizar $user. Cómo lo puedo solventar? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Simplemente borra el `return` y después del evento pones `return $user`. Te recomiendo que repases las bases de la programación antes de intentar usar frameworks como Laravel, que son realmente complicados y extensos. Saber cómo funcionan los elementos de control de flujo es muy importante, y el error que tienes es muy básico. Cualquier IDE de hecho te advertiría de que ese evento no se está disparando y te marcaría un error porque jamás se puede poner nada tras un `return`

Comment: Si muchas gracias. Lo solventé de esa manera! si lo agregas como respuesta te doy la recompensa!

Comment: No hago esto por los puntos. Y siempre hay a quien le interesan más :) Me alegra que lo solucionases, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El método create debe quedar así:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'tipo_usuario' => $tipoUsuario,
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'apellido' => $data['apellido'],
        'telefono' => $data['celular'],
        'telegram' => $data['telegram'],
        'documento' => $data['documento'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
    event(new Registered($user));
    return $user;

}
```

También En `App\User` debes implementar la interfaz `MustVerifyEmail`, de manera que debe quedarte así:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    // ...
}
```

Una vez que se haya agregado esta interfaz a su modelo, los usuarios recién registrados recibirán automáticamente un correo electrónico con un enlace de verificación por correo electrónico.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#model-preparation

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta. Te hago una pregunta más. La primera vez que se registra un usuario no envía el mail, funciona si se hace clic en haga "clic solicitar otro mail". ¿Qué puede ser?

Comment: @maraet si la respuesta te ha servido, recuerda marcarla como lista y aceptada.